# Add metadata to an image in windows phone 8

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, metadata

I would like to add custom metadata to my image in my windows phone 8 application. Is this possible and how?

I have taken a photo in my application on my WP8 device and I have dragged it to my Windows computer to check the tags...

I would like to add the "Title", "Subject" "Tags" metadata to my image when I take the photo in my WP8 application

[image]

Comment: Pls check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709942.aspx If you need to add custom data, try adding the data and path of your file to isolated storage so that you can retrieve it later.

Comment: I probably used the word Custom in the wrong sense. I meant things such as `Title`, `Subject` and `Tags`

Comment: May be you can have a local DB to store all of this.I am still unable to understand your context..Later would you like to show up list of images based on tags or something?

Comment: Ok. I have updated the question to try make it clearer

Comment: The first link which I gave is the answer then.. did u try that?

Comment: I cant find the namespace `Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder` do I need to reference a library?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59804/discussion-between-prasanna-aarthi-and-user1).